# Unhandled exception Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1] when deploying Aspnet Blazor server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'd appreciate if I could get some pointers on how to fix this, when deploying SIGNALIR to production:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
         at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MailLobbyer.Pages.Email.OnInitializedAsync() in /home/kitt/Documents/GitHub/MailLobbyer/src/MailLobbyer/Pages/Email.razor:line 148
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<WaitForQuiescence>g__ProcessAsynchronousWork|48_0()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.WaitForQuiescence()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(Int32 componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c__11`1.<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedServerComponentAsync(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, Object parameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
         at MailLobbyer.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__14_1() in /home/kitt/Documents/GitHub/MailLobbyer/src/MailLobbyer/Pages/_Host.cshtml:line 19
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
         at MailLobbyer.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

I've tried implementing solutions provided surrounding this exception in other projects, along with testing in a development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, there are two possible problems which can cause this exception:

- You don´t authorize yourself when calling request
- You don´t have error handler configured

You can check if you have some handling set up when in non development(production) environment:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())  //non development
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");   //handle exception
}
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

And controller for that

```
[Route("/error")]
public IActionResult HandleError() =>
    Problem();
```

Explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exception-handler

Comment: I do have error handling but I definitely need to add authorization for SignalIR, thanks!